# Open files in network not working

Tags: javascript

I have WAMP installed on a network machine. I have a table with file links, for people could open those files directly from a web page.
Those files are in another server, in the same network as WAMP.
When the users click on the link it appears the following error: 
"not allowed to load local resource:  file:///networkdrive/directorie/file.xls"

How can I resolve this?

I have this:

```
<button type="button" onClick="openfile('networkdrive/ptlr/Sectorial/LRCD/Horários/Equipas Turno.xls')">botao</button>

<script>

function openfile(file) {

    window.location = "file:///" + file;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Well, what is `networkdrive` supposed to be?

Comment: When I map a new network, it's that name I gave. So I have G:\, instead of "networkdrive"

Answer (score 0):

Just read the error: "**not allowed** to load local resource (...)"

Or on Firefox I get "Access to (...) from script **denied**".

It seems you are looking for a magical solution that will solve it, but no, it's exactly as the description of the error says: you are not allowed to do that because of security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to make the browser open a file on your local drive, and that's not allowed from any protocol other than `file:///` itself. So, what you'll want to do is either make sure the local file is also accessible via a server, or open the webpages that contain this script from `file:///` too.

You can see this at work by first opening http://jsbin.com/OYObEMA/1/ and seeing this same error occur, then pressing CTRL+S and saving it as a single HTML file, and opening that HTML file then. The JSBin one opens via the internet, so isn't given access to the `file:///` protocol, but the local (downloaded) HTML file can access it.

One way you could kind-of do this is to just provide the url the user needs to go to instead. So, just make an `<input>` that has a `value` set to the url the user would need to go to, and then provide the instructions "please copy this url into your url bar to open this file". That's not an elegant way to do it, but it would kind-of work.

Comment: So how can I do this? I thought I could do this like making a download file from another server. I thought this would give me the "open/save file dialog". So as I understood, it's not possible to make what I want? (Having a table with links to another server that I have access on my local machine). :(

Comment: It is not possible to let a script open a local file, no. It is possible though to let a script open an **online** file, which will indeed open up the "open/save" dialog. This can't be a file on something like `file:///G:/` though. So yes it is possible to make a table like that, but you'll have to access those files via the internet, not via a local file.

Comment: And there's no way to configure WAMP to link to the other server and download the files on WAMP server? Dam'it, now I'm getting sad...

Comment: @user1842540 see my edit (bottom paragraph). Maybe that helps?

Comment: Sorry, now I read your edited comments. I think I will try to do one button, when people press it it do a "copy" the link to the clipboard and then they will past it on the windows explorer. Thats it. You have a code of how to do this? thank you joey for your clarifications about my question. Best regards.

Comment: Accessing the user's clipboard is really complicated, and it usually requires the user to give permission to access it first, before you can use it. It's probably better to just put the `file:///` url in the input, then the user can select it, copy it, and open it in Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

About your answer to my initial comment: sure, I understood that. The question was not meant in a literal way, but to make you start thinking about what you actually try! You mix different environments.

1. either need to use `webdav` for this, if your client side applications are able to use that http extension to load and save files, or
2. you have to do the old scheme known from the IT middleages which is still typical for MS-Windows systems: offer the file for download via http and add an additional upload service (which will give you versioning pain), or
3. deliver your web page via the same protocol (network share) so that it is opened with as a local file on the client side, since then your *are* allowed to open additional local files referenced inside the web page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm on my job and try to put the webpage in one folder on the server drive I want to get the files (I had to make a "save as" of my php file and make a HTML file with the table I want). So, If I have the page on the server, this is working:     <a href="//server1/ptlr/Sectorial/LRCD/Horários/Equipas Turno.xls" target="_blank">edpprtfs1</a>
    <a href="G:/Sectorial/LRCD/Horários/Equipas Turno.xls" target="_blank">Drive Local</a>
But both start automatically downloading the files, and what is supposed to do is open them :(. It's complicated to ask something to the IT dep

Comment: How a browser handles the files referenced by a hyper link is controlled by http headers sent when starting to transfer the file.